# Unable to convert a table to hypertable due to unique index error

Tags: postgresql, python, timescaledb, sqlalchemy

I am creating a table using Flask SQL Alchemy as follows:

```
class Price(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "prices"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    country_code = db.Column(db.String(2), nullable=False)
    value = db.Column(db.Float(precision=2), nullable=False)
    start = db.Column(db.DateTime(timezone=True), nullable=False)
    end = db.Column(db.DateTime(timezone=True), nullable=False)
    price_type = db.Column(db.String(32), nullable=False)
```

and then I want to create the table and convert it into hypertable by doing:

```
def register_timescale():
    result = db.session.execute(
        "select exists(select * from timescaledb_information.hypertable " +
        " where table_name='prices')")
    is_hypertable = [row[0] for row in result]
    if is_hypertable[0] is False:
        db.session.execute(
            "SELECT create_hypertable('prices', 'start', chunk_time_interval=>INTERVAL '1 day')")
        db.session.commit()


def create_app(app_config):
    app = Flask(__name__)

    app.config.from_object(app_config)

    register_extensions(app)
    register_blueprints(app)
    with app.app_context():
        db.create_all()
        register_timescale()
    return app
```

I want to create a hypertable of the table `prices` with the `start` column being `time_column_name` as described at [create_hypertable](https://docs.timescale.com/latest/api#create_hypertable) and the `chunk_time_interval` should be 1 day. Meaning, one chunk must have data of 1 day

**Example:**

One chunk must contain data where `start` value is `2020-04-19 00:00:00+02` and `end` value is `2020-04-20 00:00:00+02` (from row 1 to 24 in the below image) and then the second chunk must contain value from `2020-04-20 00:00:00+02` till `2020-04-21 00:00:00+02` (from row 25 to 48 in the below image) and so on.

When I do this, I am getting the following error:

> Exception has occurred: DatabaseError (psycopg2.DatabaseError) cannot
>   create a unique index without the column "start" (used in
>   partitioning)
>
> [SQL: SELECT create_hypertable('prices', 'start',
>   chunk_time_interval=>INTERVAL '1 day')] (Background on this error at:
>   http://sqlalche.me/e/4xp6)

Then, I tried changing the `register_timescale()` function as follows:

```
def register_timescale():
    result = db.session.execute(
        "select exists(select * from timescaledb_information.hypertable " +
        " where table_name='prices')")
    is_hypertable = [row[0] for row in result]
    if is_hypertable[0] is False:
        db.session.execute(
            "ALTER DATABASE mydb SET timezone TO 'Europe/Berlin'")
        db.session.execute("SELECT pg_reload_conf()")
        db.session.execute("ALTER TABLE prices ADD PRIMARY KEY (id, start)")
        db.session.execute(
            "SELECT create_hypertable('prices', (id, start), chunk_time_interval=>INTERVAL '1 day')")
        db.session.commit()
```

And this gives me the following error:

> Exception has occurred: ProgrammingError
>   (psycopg2.errors.InvalidTableDefinition) multiple primary keys for
>   table "prices" are not allowed
>
> [SQL: ALTER TABLE prices ADD PRIMARY KEY (id, start)] (Background on
>   this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/f405)

My data looks as follows

[image]

Can someone please point out the mistake I am doing?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TimescaleDB requires that unique and primary keys include the time dimension column. While only one column can be defined as the time dimension. You can read about limitations in [create_hypertable doc](https://docs.timescale.com/latest/api#create_hypertable).

Since Flask SQL Alchemy requires a primary key, you can define a compound primary key on the time dimension column, which is `start` in your case, and `id`. Based on [this doc](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/faq/ormconfiguration.html#faq-mapper-primary-key) I believe it will be:

```
class Price(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "prices"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    country_code = db.Column(db.String(2), nullable=False)
    value = db.Column(db.Float(precision=2), nullable=False)
    start = db.Column(db.DateTime(timezone=True), primary_key=True)
    end = db.Column(db.DateTime(timezone=True), nullable=False)
    price_type = db.Column(db.String(32), nullable=False)
```

Then you should be able to execute `create_hypertable` statement successfully. It should include only column `start` as the time dimension, i.e.:

```sql
SELECT create_hypertable('prices', 'start', chunk_time_interval=>INTERVAL '1 day')
```

Note that `create_hypertable` will also create the default index on `start`. Depending on your application queries you might not need this index and the primary key might be enough. In such case you can drop the index on `start` either by setting option `create_default_indexes` to `false` during the call to create hypertable or by executing `DROP INDEX` statement afterwards. [The best practice section](https://docs.timescale.com/latest/using-timescaledb/schema-management#indexing-best-practices) contains more information.

Comment: Hey, @k_rus, I tried your suggestion of making `start` as PK in flask, and when I still do  ```db.session.execute("SELECT create_hypertable('prices', (id, start), chunk_time_interval=>INTERVAL '1 day')")```, I get the error: `column "id" does not exist`

Comment: As I mentioned you can only specify single column as the time dimension, i.e., `start`.

Comment: Updated the comment.

Comment: Now, when I run the code it gives the following error: `psycopg2.errors.NotNullViolation: null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (null, DE, 25.18, 2020-03-20 00:00:00+01, 2020-03-20 01:00:00+01, DAY_AHEAD)`

Comment: I solved the `null` issue by doing `id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)`.

Comment: I just have one last question. Is it possible to store the chunks as I explained in the question?

Comment: Do you mean a chunk per a day? It depends on the data volume. [This article](https://docs.timescale.com/latest/using-timescaledb/hypertables#best-practices) discusses the best practice.

Comment: Hey @k_rus, Is it possible that `chunk_time_interval=>INTERVAL '1 day'` is assumed in `UTC` and that it the `INTERVAL` has to be set to `Europe/Berlin` to respect the timezone while splitting the data into chunks?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108008/discussion-between-k-rus-and-junkrat).